# Calendar stuck on 'edit event' screen

Tags: ios, calendar

My I Phone 5 calendar is stuck on Edit Event -won't allow me to save the event it is displaying or delete the event  What can I do?

Comment: What happens if you force-quit the calendar app? Or restart your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Try quitting the app. Double-click the home button, then swipe up on the Calendar app. Return to the home screen and open Calendar again.